# Error with web.py uploading <type 'exceptions.IOError'>

Tags: python, web.py, uploading, storage

So i am  following the web.py uploading and storing guide to test it out but i keep geting a 
 error stating that [Errno 2] No such file or directory :< help

this is my code

```
import web

urls = (
    '/hello', 'index',
    '/hello/upload', 'upload'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals()) # handels http request  that aks for urls 
# the base ells lpthw.web to use the templates/layout.html file as the base template for all the other templates
render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")
# must use port 127.0.0.1:5000
class index(object):

    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

class upload(object):

    def POST(self):
        x = web.input(files={})

        filedir = '/project/webtest/templates'  # directory were you want to save the file 
        if 'files' in x:  # check if the file -object is created
            filepath=x.files.filename.replace('\\','/') # replace the windows -style slashes with linux ones
            filename=filepath.split('/')[-1] #splits the and chooses the last part (the filename with extension
            fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename,'w') # creates the file where the uploaded file should be stored
            fout.write(x.files.file.read()) #writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.            
            fout.close() #closes the file 
        else:
            return "Error no file" 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals()) 
    app.run()
```

help thx

Answer (score 0):

```
import web

urls = ('/upload', 'Upload')

class Upload:
def GET(self):
    web.header("Content-Type","text/html; charset=utf-8")
    return view.upload()
def POST(self):
    x = web.input(myfile={})
    filedir = '/path/where/you/want/to/save' # change this to the directory you want to store the file in.
    if 'myfile' in x: # to check if the file-object is created
        filepath=x.myfile.filename.replace('\\','/') 
        filename=filepath.split('/')[-1] 
        fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename,'w') 
        fout.write(x.myfile.file.read()) # writes the uploaded file to the newly created file.
        fout.close() # closes the file, upload complete.
    raise web.seeother('/upload')


if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = web.application(urls, globals()) 
   app.run()


upload.html
<html>
 <head>
 <title>File upload</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input type="file" name="myfile" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

for your reference http://webpy.org/cookbook/storeupload/

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem myself, and tried to ask that here. But nobody answers.

Finally, I figured it out what's the problem and would like to share with you!

This part: `filedir = '/project/webtest/templates'` should be an absolute path.

And it should be an existing directory (at least in my trail it should be an existing directory, otherwise it would prompt the same error as you posted)! The file need not to be exciting since we are going to create it by copying the uploaded file.

For example in my mac, it's `'/Users/J/pythonex/projects/gothonweb/docs'`, and it's an existing directory. If it's not an existing directory, you will get the same error message.

Last, the most tricky part. Im my mac, the uploaded files are actually stored in my disk in that exact directory. But I can't see them in my finder until I relaunch the finder. I don't know why is that. But for my computer, that's the case.